# Why is connecting from localhost by some libraries possible and by others not possible?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, httprequest, httpserver

Both this library [restup](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup) (written by [tomkuijsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381932/tom-kuijsten)) and this library [SimpleHttpServer](https://github.com/jeske/SimpleHttpServer) implement HTTP server functionality and provide a clean API to embed and use it in UWP projects.

As stated in the first point of the FAQ [here](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup/wiki/FAQ#1-i-cant-connect-to-restup--headeddemo--headlessdemo-from-my-local-machine) and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665847/cannot-connect-to-streamsocketlistener), restup cannot be called by the local machine (I tried even to run a virtual machine, setup a network using a virtual network adapter, but in vain).

But the question is, why is it then possible by [SimpleHttpServer](https://github.com/jeske/SimpleHttpServer)!?

Comment: Do both listen on the same port number?

Comment: You might try turning off windows firewall and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the network socket of the server can be bound to either 0.0.0.0 (All), or explicitly to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), or the IP address of network card eg 192.168.0.2. Secondly HTTP/1.1 requires the host entered into the url to be passed as a header to the server. So either your request isn't sent to the right IP address, the server is rejecting the request based on the Host header, or some other firewall issue is blocking the request.

Answer (score 0):

Restup is using a StreamSocketListener and SimpleHttp is using TcpListener. This would be why the one works locally and the other doesn't.